# deploy server selection in Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

Is there any plug-in or configuration that I add to jenkins server and make me able to select my favorite destination server for deployment ? 
I could add configuration to jenkins which makes me able to select "the branch" that I want to build. with a cascade menu .  I want some thing the same , for destination server.

Answer (score 1):

There is an option called "Restrict where this project can be run" where you can specify which servers the job should be run. For that you have to label your servers. You can do that under Manage nodes section of Jenkins. 
To make the choice at run time, you can launch the jobs via Jenkins cli and populate the Label parameter with desired value. I am looking for the site where I picked up this info but have not been able to find it till now.

Check if these two sites help:

http://michael-prokop.at/blog/2014/03/01/jenkins-on-demand-slave-selection-through-labels/

https://developer.cloudbees.com/bin/view/DEV/On-Premise+Executors

Comment: I found the solution. It is actually combination of this two articles : first step-> https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Step+by+step+guide+to+set+up+master+and+slave+machines

Second-> https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/NodeLabel+Parameter+Plugin

if you follow this two articles. you would have a selective menu when you want to build the software. You can select your destination server to build. Thanks all of you for your hints

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution. It is actually combination of this two articles : 
first step-> https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Step+by+step+guide+to+set+up+master+and+slave+machines

Second->  https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/NodeLabel+Parameter+Plugin

if you follow this two articles. you would have a selective menu when you want to build the software. You can select your destination server to build.
Thanks all of you for your hints.